# Python Pandas Least Extreme of Three Row Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 rows of `DataFrame` each stored in separate variables. How can I create a new `pandas` `DataFrame` so that it contains the least extreme element of each `columns`?

So if I had:

```
x:    
                    C2        CL2          ED  ES  RB2
1992-12-30 -200.145189 -36.711906  108.067018 NaN  NaN

y:

                    C2        CL2          ED  ES  RB2
1992-12-30 -250.145189 -21.000000  107.067018 NaN  NaN

z:

                    C2        CL2          ED  ES  RB2
1992-12-30 -249.145189 -31.711906  100.067018 NaN  NaN
```

I want back something:

```
                    C2        CL2          ED  ES  RB2
1992-12-30 -200.145189 -21.000000  100.067018 NaN  NaN
```

I can do it with loops but was hoping for a more elegant/efficient solution because this can get big in terms of number of elements in each row.

thanks

Comment: there's a singe row in each DataFrame?

Comment: yea only 1 row in each dataframe

Comment: Is the column with dates significant? In other words: will you have to also find the minimum date? The solutions posted won't do that if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating sample data - three single-row `DataFrames` with positive and negative values, and use `pd.concat()` to combine for calculation:

```
import string
import pandas as pd

df = {}
for i in range(3):
    df[i] = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.uniform(-5, 5, size=10), index=list(string.ascii_uppercase)[:10]).transpose()
df = pd.concat(list(df.values()))

          A         B         C         D         E         F         G  \
0 -4.754784  1.193108  0.322375 -1.621932 -2.310099  1.710547 -4.272505   
0 -1.806019 -3.790956  4.111070 -3.034269  0.607244  2.020302 -0.340587   
0 -4.130075  3.218974 -3.791859  0.835340 -3.245390  1.738022  0.162090   

          H         I         J  
0  0.315760  0.805558 -0.134248  
0 -1.608740  2.932232  1.905336  
0  1.423596 -4.437640  0.868514
```

Apply function to each column that returns the value associated with the `index` of the `min` `abs` value like so:

```
import numpy as np
df.apply(lambda x: x[(np.abs(x)).argmin()], raw=True)

A   -1.806019
B    1.193108
C    0.322375
D    0.835340
E    0.607244
F    1.710547
G    0.162090
H    0.315760
I    0.805558
J   -0.134248
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Will this will work if the date column is a datetime dtype?

Comment: `Date` is the `index` in the example, and the OP is looking for values closest to zero in the `columns`. It's also not quite clear how to determine the 'least extreme' date, doesn't necessarily have to be the minimum date.

Comment: Yes, thanks, it will ignore the index. Should have confirmed it myself before asking the question, but the fingers type faster than the brain thinks sometimes... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can temporarily concatenate them, then take the index of minimum of the absolute values:

```
pd.concat([x, y, z]).ix[pd.concat([x, y, z]).abs().idxmin()]
```

Comment: Will this will work if the date column is a datetime dtype?

Comment: It looks like the dates are index values, so the abs and min functions aren't applied to the index.

Comment: I really like your answer, but when I reconstructed the dataframe and used your answer like this: df.ix[df.abs().idxmin()] it didn't work. First, when the index was a datetime it threw an exception, and then when I dropped the date column altogether it didn't handle the NaN properly.

Comment: Would you post the code you used to reconstruct the dataframe?

Comment: Sure. See my post. Thanks!